# What governs the ability to move the limit inside the limit of an exponential?

Tags: limits

For example, let's say we have some expression:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp(f(n))
$$

This can be solved as
$$
\exp(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n))
$$

What governs the ability that allows us to move the limit inside the exponential? Based on [When can I move the limit operand into a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518738/when-can-i-move-the-limit-operand-into-a-function), it seems the function (exponential in this case) has to be continuous.

Is that the only requirement? Are there any requirements for things like convexity or monotonicity of the function?

Comment: You can always prove it using the epsilon delta proof or another definition of the limit.

Comment: You need two things: 1. $\lim f(n)$ needs to exist and be finite. 2. $\exp$ must be continuous at $\lim f(n)$. Try to prove that you can interchange the limit given these conditions.